# Makefile and gcc error

Tags: makefile

In my makefile, I'm getting the following error when running 'make tests':
make: *** No rule to make target `GenRangeTreeTester', needed by`tests'.  Stop.

```
tests: GenRangeTreeTester libGenRangeTree.a
    gcc -Wall -L. -lGenRangeTree Teacher.o Manager.o -o GenRangeTreeTester
    ./GenRangeTreeTester
.PHONY: tests
```

But actually GenRangeTreeTester and libGenRangeTree.a aren't exist so why doesn't it run the gcc call ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `tests: GenRangeTreeTester libGenRangeTree.a` means that target `tests` **depends on** `GenRangeTreeTester`. A file must be present with that name for the commands below to be executed.

Change your Makefile like this:

```
tests: GenRangeTreeTester 
    ./GenRangeTreeTester

GenRangeTreeTester: libGenRangeTree.a
    gcc -Wall -L. -lGenRangeTree Teacher.o Manager.o -o GenRangeTreeTester
```

Answer (score 0):

Your telling it that tests depends on GenRangeTreeTeset and libGenRangeTree and make is telling you it can't find a build rule for GenRangeTreeTester and that it doesn't exist.

It's not running gcc, make won't continue without the dependencies being up to date (and actually existing :) ).

Hope that clears it up for you.